# Custom Recipient list will not populate using custom button in SFDC for Docusign

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

I have my button fully working except my CRL won't populate and can't determine why.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_JavaScript")} 
var RC="";var RSL="";var RSRO="";var RROS="";var CCRM="";var CCTM="";var CCNM="";var CRCL="";var     OCO="";var DST="";var LA="";var CEM="";var CES="";var STB="";var SSB="";var SES="";var SEM="";var SRS="";var SCS ="";var RES=""; 
RC=""; 
RSL="2"; 
RSRO=""; 
RROS=""; 
CCRM=""; 
CRL="LoadDefaultContacts~0;Email~matt.xxxx@powerreviews.com;FirstName~Matt;LastName~xxxx;Role~Signer 2;RoutingOrder~2";
CCTM=""; 
CCNM=""; 
CRCL=""; 
OCO=""; 
DST=""; 
LA="0";
```

CEM="Hello {!dsfs__DocuSign_Envelope__c.dsfs__Contact2eSignDoc01__c}\nI am sending you this request for your electronic signature, please review and electronically sign by following the link below.\nWe highly recommend that you use the electronic signature to speed the process, however, if you do need to sign manually, please click the MORE button at the top of the Docusign screen and select the 'Sign on Paper' option - and complete the process as defined in the dialog box in Docusign.   Otherwise, there may be delays in the execution of this process.\nWe appreciate your cooperation."; 
    CES="PowerReviews Request to eSign Contracts - {!Account.Name}"; 
    STB="1"; 
    SSB="1"; 
    SES="1"; 
    SEM="1"; 
    SRS="1"; 
    SCS="1"; 
    RES="1,2,2,1,15,3"; 
    window.location.href = "/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope?DSEID=0&SourceID={!Opportunity.Id}&RC="+RC+"&RSL="+RSL+"&RSRO="+RSRO+"&RROS="+RROS+"&CCRM="+CCRM+"&CCTM="+CCTM+"&CRCL="+CRCL+"&OCO="+OCO+"&DST="+DST+"&CCNM="+CCNM+"&LA="+LA+"&CEM="+CEM+"&CES="+CES+"&SRS="+SRS+"&STB="+STB+"&SSB="+SSB+"&SES="+SES+"&SEM="+SEM+"&SRS="+SRS+"&SCS="+SCS+"&RES="+RES;

Answer (score 1):

The CRL was not populated because of two reasons. Firstly, the recipient list should be separated by a comma and not a semicolon. Secondly,CRL was not called in the page callout section.
I have modified the script to pull the custom recipient list.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_JavaScript")} 
var RC="";var RSL="";var RSRO="";var RROS="";var CCRM="";var CCTM="";var CCNM="";var CRCL="";var     OCO="";var DST="";var LA="";var CEM="";var CES="";var STB="";var SSB="";var SES="";var SEM="";var SRS="";var SCS ="";var RES=""; 
RC=""; 
RSL="2"; 
RSRO=""; 
RROS=""; 
CCRM=""; 
CRL="LoadDefaultContacts~0,Email~matt.xxxx@powerreviews.com;FirstName~Matt;LastName~xxxx;Role~Signer 2;RoutingOrder~2";
CCTM=""; 
CCNM=""; 
CRCL=""; 
OCO=""; 
DST=""; 
LA="0"; 
CEM="Hello {!dsfs__DocuSign_Envelope__c.dsfs__Contact2eSignDoc01__c}\nI am sending you this request for your electronic signature, please review and electronically sign by following the link below.\nWe highly recommend that you use the electronic signature to speed the process, however, if you do need to sign manually, please click the MORE button at the top of the Docusign screen and select the 'Sign on Paper' option - and complete the process as defined in the dialog box in Docusign. Otherwise, there may be delays in the execution of this process.\nWe appreciate your cooperation."; CES="PowerReviews Request to eSign Contracts - {!Account.Name}"; STB="1"; SSB="1"; SES="1"; SEM="1"; SRS="1"; SCS="1"; RES="1,2,2,1,15,3"; window.location.href = "/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope?DSEID=0&SourceID={!Opportunity.Id}&RC="+RC+"&RSL="+RSL+"&RSRO="+RSRO+"&RROS="+RROS+"&CCRM="+CCRM+"&CCTM="+CCTM+"&CRCL="+CRCL+"&OCO="+OCO+"&DST="+DST+"&CCNM="+CCNM+"&LA="+LA+"&CEM="+CEM+"&CES="+CES+"&SRS="+SRS+"&STB="+STB+"&SSB="+SSB+"&SES="+SES+"&SEM="+SEM+"&SRS="+SRS+"&SCS="+SCS+"&RES="+RES+"&CRL="+CRL;
```